# how to display a different navbar when the user is logged into the site

Tags: python, mongodb, session, flask

I'm creating a cookbook for my project and am trying to switch the nabvar when the user is logged into the
website so it displays 'recipes, add recipes, logout' and hides the 'login and register links'. I was following this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVx1737auSE but when I log into the site the nav isn't changing.

Navigation:

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
  {% if session.user %}      
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('recipes')}}"> Recipes</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('add_recipe') }}" >Add Recipe</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('logout') }}" >Logout</a>
    </li>       
    {% else %}
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('login')}}">Login</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{url_for('register')}}">Register</a>
  </li>   
   {% endif %}
  </li>   
</ul>
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, session, redirect, request, flash

import bcrypt


@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():   
 if request.method == 'POST':
     users = mongo.db.users
     login_user = users.find_one({'name' : request.form['username']})
     if login_user:
         if bcrypt.hashpw(request.form['password'].encode('utf-8'), login_user['password']) == login_user['password']:
             session['username'] = request.form['username']
             flash('You have been successfully logged in!')
             return redirect(url_for('index'))        
     return 'Invalide username/password combination'
 return render_template('pages/login.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are adding the key `username` into the session with `login` route called, you need check `session.username` in your jinja template.